# getting checkbox value from ag-grid column

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have a checkbox in an ag-grid that I'm displaying the following way:

```
  {header: 'Cancel', 
    field: 'IsCancel', 
    cellRenderer: params => {
      return `<input type='checkbox' ${params.value ? 'checked': ''} />`
    }  
  }
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that when the user clicks the Save button, I go thru each row and find out which checkbox has been checked.

I've tried using the code below to find out which checkbox has been checked.  Unfortunately, node.data.IsCancel is false even when I check a checkbox in the ag-grid:

```
  saveCustomer() {
    this.api.forEachNode(this.printNode)
  }

  printNode(node, index) {
    console.log('Customer Number is: ' + node.data.CustomerNumber);
    console.log('Cancel is: ' + node.data.IsCancel);
    if (node.data.IsCancel.checked) {
      console.log('Customer Number in checked is: ' + node.data.CustomerNumber);
    }
  }
```

Here is all of the code:

cancellation.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="loadCancellation">
  <ag-grid-angular class="ag-fresh"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [rowData]="customerNames"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    class="ag-theme-balham">
  </ag-grid-angular>
  <br/>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="saveCustomer()">Save</button>
</div>
```

cancellation.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, AfterViewInit, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomerNameService } from '../customer-name.service';
import { CustomerNameCancellation } from '../customername-cancellation';
import { ColDef, GridApi, ColumnApi } from 'ag-grid-community';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cancellation',
  templateUrl: './cancellation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cancellation.component.css']
})
export class CancellationComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('zipCode') zipCode: string;
  @Input('lastName') lastName: string;
  customerNames: Array<CustomerNameCancellation>;

  private api: GridApi;
  columnApi: ColumnApi;
  columnDefs: ColDef[];
  loadCancellation: boolean;
  params: any;

  constructor (private customerNameService: CustomerNameService) {
   this.columnDefs = this.createColumnDefs(); 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.customerNameService
    .getCustomerNames(this.zipCode, this.lastName)
    .subscribe(data => {this.customerNames = data;})
    console.log("finished loading customers");
    console.log("zipcode is: " + this.zipCode);
    console.log("lastname is: " + this.lastName);
    this.loadCancellation = true;
  }

  onGridReady(params) : void {
    this.api = params.api;
    this.columnApi = params.columnApi;
    this.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    this.params = params;
  }

  private createColumnDefs() {
    return [
      {header: 'Customer Number', field: 'CustomerNumber', sortable: true, filter: true},
      {header: 'First Name', field: 'FirstName', sortable: true, filter: true},
      {header: 'Middle Name', field: 'MiddleName', sortable: true, filter: true},
      {header: 'Last Name', field: 'LastName', sortable: true, filter: true},
      {header: 'Address', field: 'Address1', sortable: true, filter: true},
      {header: 'City', field: 'City', sortable: true, filter: true},
      {header: 'State', field: 'StateCd', sortable: true, filter: true},
      {header: 'Zip Code', field: 'ZipCode', sortable: true, filter: true},
      {header: 'Magazine Code', field: 'MagazineCd', sortable: true, filter: true},
      {header: 'Cancel', 
        field: 'IsCancel', 
        cellRenderer: params => {
          return `<input type='checkbox' ${params.value ? 'checked': ''} "/>`
        }  
      },
      {header: 'Cancellation Date', field: 'CancellationDate', sortable: true, filter: true}
    ]
  }

  saveCustomer() {
    this.api.forEachNode(this.printNode)
  }

  printNode(node, index) {
    console.log('Customer Number is: ' + node.data.CustomerNumber);
    console.log('Cancel is: ' + node.data.IsCancel);
    if (node.data.IsCancel.checked) {
      console.log('Customer Number in checked is: ' + node.data.CustomerNumber);
    }
  }

  public checkedVal() {
    console.log(this.params.node.data);
    console.log(this.params.value); 
  }

}
```

**Update**
I also tried using checkboxSelection: true.  But it shows "true" or "false" right next to the checkbox.

**Updated #2**

I used checkboxSelection: true.

There are two issues:

1) The value "true" or "false" shows next to the checkbox.  Please see the image.

2) For those checkboxes that already come back as "true" from the database, the checkbox isn't already checked.

[image]

Here is the updated code:

```
import { Component, Input, AfterViewInit, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomerNameService } from '../customer-name.service';
import { CustomerNameCancellation } from '../customername-cancellation';
import { ColDef, GridApi, ColumnApi } from 'ag-grid-community';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cancellation',
  templateUrl: './cancellation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cancellation.component.css']
})
export class CancellationComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('zipCode') zipCode: string;
  @Input('lastName') lastName: string;
  customerNames: Array<CustomerNameCancellation>;

  private api: GridApi;
  columnApi: ColumnApi;
  columnDefs: ColDef[];
  loadCancellation: boolean;
  params: any;

  constructor (private customerNameService: CustomerNameService) {
   this.columnDefs = this.createColumnDefs(); 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.customerNameService
    .getCustomerNames(this.zipCode, this.lastName)
    .subscribe(data => {this.customerNames = data;})
    console.log("finished loading customers");
    console.log("zipcode is: " + this.zipCode);
    console.log("lastname is: " + this.lastName);
    this.loadCancellation = true;
  }

  onGridReady(params) : void {
    this.api = params.api;
    this.columnApi = params.columnApi;
    this.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    this.params = params;
  }

  private createColumnDefs() {
    return [
      {headerName: 'Customer Number', field: 'CustomerNumber', sortable: true, filter: true},
      {headerName: 'First Name', field: 'FirstName', sortable: true, filter: true},
      {headerName: 'Middle Name', field: 'MiddleName', sortable: true, filter: true},
      {headerName: 'Last Name', field: 'LastName', sortable: true, filter: true},
      {headerName: 'Address', field: 'Address1', sortable: true, filter: true},
      {headerName: 'City', field: 'City', sortable: true, filter: true},
      {headerName: 'State', field: 'StateCd', sortable: true, filter: true},
      {headerName: 'Zip Code', field: 'ZipCode', sortable: true, filter: true},
      {headerName: 'Magazine Code', field: 'MagazineCd', sortable: true, filter: true},
      {headerName: 'Cancel', 
        field:'IsCancel',
        editable: true, 
        sortable: true,
        filter: true,
        checkboxSelection:true 
      },
      // {header: 'Cancel', 
      //   field: 'IsCancel', 
      //   cellRenderer: params => {
      //     return `<input type='checkbox' ${params.value ? 'checked': ''} "/>`
      //   }  
      // },
      {header: 'Cancellation Date', field: 'CancellationDate', sortable: true, filter: true}
    ]
  }

  saveCustomer() {
    // this.api.forEachNode(this.printNode)
    let selectedRows;
    selectedRows = this.api.getSelectedRows();
    console.log(selectedRows);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For check box selection you can use checkboxSelection: true in you columnDef instead to use cell render:

```
this.columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: 'Name',
    field: 'testName',
    checkboxSelection: true, //HERE !!!!
    width: 150
  }
```

and than you can easy get rows, when checkbox selected :

```
someMethod() {
  let selectedRows;
  selectedRows = this.gridApi.getSelectedRows();
  console.log(selectedRows);
  ///than you can map your selectedRows 
  selectedRows.map((row) => {
   console.log(row);
   console.log(row.data);
  });
}
```

If you need to set checked or not depended on data from dataBase you can use:

```
     onGridReady(params) {
        this.gridApi = params.api;
        this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
        this.transportApi.getCustomerNames().subscribe((res) => {
          this.rowData = res;
          if (res) {        
 this.transportApi.getSelectedCustomerNames().subscribe((selectedCustomers) => {
                if (selectedCustomers) {
                  this.gridApi.forEachNode((node) => {
                    selectedCustomers.map((customer) => {
                      if (node.data.CustomerNumber=== customer.CustomerNumber) {
                        node.setSelected(true);
                      }
                    });
                  });
                }
              });


            }
          }
        }, error1 => console.log(error1));
      }
```

Transport method is example use yours in code;

Comment: I had tried the checkboxSelection: true option. The only thing I don't like about that is that it shows "true" or "false" right next to the checkbox.  Please see update in original post.

Comment: I dont understand, why you need to use cellRenderer for checkbox selection. Try to use it without cellRenderer.

Comment: I did try "checkboxSelection: true", but it also shows the value "true" or "false" next to the checkbox.  Please see the image I included in the original post.

Comment: And dont use cellRenderer for checkBox selection. Simple add checkboxSelection: true to column where you wanna add checkbox

Comment: Please see the second upate to my original post.  It shows that I'm using checkbox selection.  And the two issues I'm having.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187571/discussion-between-anton-skybun-and-rds80).

Comment: @AntonSkybun How do I make checkbox `checked` based on the data from the database when using the server-side model? Right now i am using `cellRendererFramework` for first column with custom `checkbox component` which uses `node.setSelected()` to mark row selected based on condition passed. But the problem with this approach is the method `api.getSelectedRows()` returns the selected rows from only rendered rows from 1st page and *other pages only if i have visited them*. *continued...*

Comment: @AntonSkybun Another problem is when I visit lets say 2nd page and `uncheck` the already `checked` row and go back to page 1 and then revisit page 2 it will mark the row `checked` again.

Comment: @SushmitSagar i need to see you code and some play with it - to clear help you. If it possible - let me know